# perl script help (time and sort )

Tags: perl

I tried to make a script but I need some help from you guys.. ıt will be like a fixing..
The output which ı had from my script and my script were sent as an attachment.

1. Can i get that output as left aligned?
2. Besides can you guys make the space smaller from "ZAMAN" to "SAHA after deleting "***ALARM" ??
3. Last thing ı want is to be come the output in an order by timing? I mean the top of the written must be the newest date..?

I will be waiting for your answer..

my script

---

```
$dosyaa="LOG.txt";
$dosya_out="KESIK_SEKTORLER.txt";

open fp1, $dosyaa;
open fp2, ">$dosya_out" or die "Cannot find $dosya_out for read\n :$!";

print fp2 "              BSC         BCF              ALARM TÜRÜ         ZAMAN                                               SAHA                     ALARM\n";

$count=0;
$SEG_NUM2=0;
$BCVI4=0;
$BTS_ST=0;
$toplam="";
$toplam2="";
$toplam_p="";
$deneme=0;

foreach $line(<fp1>) {
    chomp($line);
    if (($line =~ /QUAL/)) {$SEG_NUM2=$line};
    if (($line =~ /ALARM/)) {$SEG_NUM3=$line};
    if (($line =~ /ALARM/) or ($line =~ /BCCH MISSING/)) {
        $BTS_ST=$line;
        if (($BTS_ST =~ /BCCH MISSING/) or ($BTS_ST =~ /ALARM/) or ($BTS_ST =~ /QUAL/))  {
            $deneme=$deneme+1
        }
    };
    if (($line =~ /BCCH MISSING/)) {
        if (($BTS_ST =~ /BCCH MISSING/) or ($BTS_ST =~ /ALARM/) or ($BTS_ST =~ /QUAL/))  {
            $BCVI4=$line,
            $toplam= "'".(substr $SEG_NUM2, 06,10)."',";
            if ($toplam ne $toplam_p) {
                $toplam2=$toplam2.$toplam;
            };
            #if ($toplam==$toplam_p) {$toplam2=$toplam2.",".$toplam};
            print fp2 "$SEG_NUM2 $SEG_NUM3 $BCVI4\n";
            $toplam_p=$toplam;
            $toplam=0,$SEG_NUM2=0,$BTS_ST=0,$BCVI4=0,$BCVI5=0,$count++;
        }
    };
}
$toplam2=substr $toplam2,0,-1;
print fp2 "           KESIK SAHA SAYISI...............$count\n";
```

### my input txt

```
       BCORK01      BCF-0021  BTS-0022    QUAL      2012-02-29  19:21:45.65
```

*** ALARM                         CO11802
   (60624) 7767 BCCH MISSING

```
       BCORK02      BCF-0031  BTS-0022    QUAL      2012-02-29  19:13:45.65
```

*** ALARM                         CO12802
   (60624) 7767 BCCH MISSING

```
       BCORK03      BCF-0041  BTS-0022    QUAL      2012-02-29  19:11:45.65
```

*** ALARM                         CO14802
   (60624) 7767 BCCH MISSING

### My output txt

```
 BSC          BCF          DATE           TIME         SAHA        ALARM
BCORK01      BCF-0021    2012-02-29     19:11:45.65   CO11801  BCH MISSING   
BCORK01      BCF-0021    2012-02-29     19:11:45.65   CO11802  BCH MISSSING 
BCORK01      BCF-0021    2012-02-29     19:11:45.65   CO11802  BCH MISSSING .
```

Comment: `enter code here` is not the way SO works.  You must show some effort to solve the problem yourself and ask specific questions.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] for more information.

Comment: If you're writing Perl then start off with `use strict; use warnings;` and while you're learning `use diagnostics;` (but remove diagnostics before putting the code into production). Trying to deal with ancient style Perl is horrible.

Comment: @JimGarrison I reacted the same way you did at first, but `enter code here` is the default message if you click the code format button on a blank line. In other words, might be a newbie typo.

Comment: @TLP ah, you are right -- forgot about that. Downvote removed.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I'd be inclined to go with your first instinct. This question reads more like an RFP with zero budget than an appropriate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

```
open fp2, ">$dosya_out" or die "Cannot find $dosya_out for read\n :$!";
```

You might start by ensuring that your error messages are reasonable :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, what you want is:

1. To trim whitespace from your input
2. Fixed column widths so everything lines up like a table
3. To sort the output based on the date & time

Try these changes. I removed some of the code to make it easier for me to read:

```
$dosyaa="LOG.txt";
$dosya_out="KESIK_SEKTORLER.txt";

open fp1, $dosyaa;
open fp2, ">$dosya_out" or die "Cannot find $dosya_out for read\n :$!";

$head_output_format="%-13s%-13s%-15s%-13s%-12s%s\n";
$body_output_format="%-13s%-12s%-15s%-14s%-9s%s\n";
printf fp2 $head_output_format, "BSC", "BCF", "DATE", "TIME", "SAHA", "ALARM";

$count=0;
$SEG_NUM2="";
$SEG_NUM3="";
%output_records = ();

foreach $line(<fp1>) {
    chomp($line);
    # Trim whitespace:
    $line =~ s/^\s+//;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;

    if (($line =~ /QUAL/)) {$SEG_NUM2=$line}
    if (($line =~ /ALARM/)) {$SEG_NUM3=$line}
    if (($line =~ /\(/)) {
        ($NUM1, $NUM2, @ALARM_split) = split (" ", $line);
        $ALARM = join (" ", @ALARM_split);
        ($BSC, $BCF, $BTS_ignore, $QUAL_ignore, $DATE, $TIME) = split (/\s+/, $SEG_NUM2);
        ($STAR_ignore, $ALARM_ignore, $SAHA) = split (" ", $SEG_NUM3);
        if ($ALARM eq "BCCH MISSING") {
            push @{$output_records{"$DATE $TIME"}}, sprintf ($body_output_format, $BSC, $BCF, $DATE, $TIME, $SAHA, $ALARM);
        }
        $SEG_NUM2="";
        $SEG_NUM3="";
        $count++;
    }
}

# sort {$b cmp $a} (reverse sort)
foreach $date_time (sort {$b cmp $a} keys(%output_records)) {
    foreach $line (@{$output_records{$date_time}}) {
        print fp2 $line;
    }
}

#print fp2 "           KESIK SAHA SAYISI...............$count\n";
```